# javascript call function with new keyword

Tags: javascript, function, new-operator

```
function outer(abc) {
  this.abc = abc;
   return function inner() {
    this.abc = abc;
    return this.abc;
  }
}
```

In the above code I cannot intantiate outer function like below

```
  var obj = new outer(123);
   console.log(obj.abc)
//here obj.abc get undefined
```

but the below code works when removed the return keyword for outer function

```
function outer(abc) {
      this.abc = abc;
       function inner() {
        this.abc = abc;
        return this.abc;
      }
    }
 var obj = new outer(123);
       console.log(obj.abc)
```

I have one more concerned is that why cannot I create object of returned function like below?

```
function outer(abc) {
      this.abc = abc;
       return function inner() {
        this.abc = abc;
        return this.abc;
      }
    }
var obj2= new outer(11)();
console.log(obj2.abc)
```

Comment: What is the point of this code? Why are you calling the function with `new` if you don't treat it as a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a function with `new` (thus creating an object instance) and return from this function the returned value will be used as result of `new` instead of this object instance. When you return a function and call it directly without binding to a context its context would be `window` in a browser:

> If the constructor function returns a non-primitive, this return value becomes the result of the whole new expression. Otherwise, if the constructor function doesn't return anything or returns a primitive, newInstance is returned instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so to override the normal object creation process.)
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

```js
function outer(abc) {
  this.abc = abc;
   return function inner() {
    console.log(this);
    this.abc = abc;
    return this.abc;
  }
}

console.log((new outer)());
```

To fix your code just remove dependence on `this`:

```js
function outer(abc) {
  this.abc = abc;
   return function inner() {
    return abc;
  }
}

console.log((new outer(123))());
```

Anyway I think your pattern here doesn't make much sense. Seems you want to achieve a pattern that would be done much cleaner and easier.
And to be more specific @VLAZ has pointed that `this.abc = abc;` in the outer class is pointless since not used later, that I noticed also but avoided to gain some focus on it. Ok as a part of JS learning though...

> @silentmantra Please clear one more doubt of below code, I will surely accept your answer. why I cant create object of inner function where it returns nothing. function outer(abc) { this.abc = abc; return function inner() { this.abc = abc; } } var result = new outer(23)(); console.dir(result);

As mentioned and shown above when you call the returned function you lose your `this` context and it becomes `window` (default one). So basically `window.abs` returned and it's `11` since you have assigned to it.
and your final `console.log(obj2.abc)` doesn't make sense since you try to get a prop of a number:

```js
function outer(abc) {
      this.abc = abc;
       return function inner() {
        this.abc = abc;       
        return this.abc;
      }
    }

var obj2= new outer(11)();

console.log(obj2)

console.log(obj2.abc) // 11 doesn't have 'abs' property

console.log(window.abc) // oops, but window has
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: In the final code block it doesn't really make any sense to use either `new` when calling the function, nor to have `this.abc = abc;` if it's never used

Comment: @VLAZ totally agree, the whole pattern doesn't make much sense, will add a note)

Comment: Here, I am experimenting and I wanna know that why I can't create object with new keyword of returned function

Comment: @AMitSiNgh then everything's great, man. Just read the MDN documentation (the link i've provided). If you're OK with the expanation don't forget to upvote and accept my question so I could be motivated to help you in the future)

Comment: @silentmantra Please clear one more doubt of below code, I will surely accept your answer.
why I cant create object of inner function where it returns nothing.

function outer(abc) {
  this.abc = abc;
    return function inner() {
    this.abc = abc;
  }
}

var result = new outer(23)();
console.dir(result);

Comment: @AMitSiNgh answered in the post

Comment: @AMitSiNgh learn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this